# Eclipse doesn't recognize Galaxy Nexus on Fedora 16

Tags: android, eclipse, fedora, galaxy-nexus

I have successfully installed Eclipse and the Android SDK on Fedora 16.  However, when I connect my Galaxy Nexus (with debugging enabled), and click Run in Eclipse, the device manager doesn't find my phone.

On Windows I had to install USB drivers for the phone but I don't believe there are any drivers for Fedora 16.

Is it possible to mount my phone AND test on Fedora 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed mtpfs and it worked after a few tries and reboots.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on DDMS, does you device show in the **Devices** window? If not, here is a list of problems to check:

Your USB cord connection to the device is too loose.

If its an old USB cord, there could be an internal break within the wires.

The socket within the device for the USB cord could be bent.

Comment: Thanks - I think it's working now.  I installed mtpfs and the thing worked after I plugged it in again.